# VBA - Using go back button shows data from first sheet

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have an Excel that functions as a sort of decision tool, where questions are being asked and one needs to navigate through the workbook with buttons.
I have made a macro to function as a "go back" button, which activates the previously active sheet and hides the one you are on now. It works, but it keeps showing the navigation buttons from the first sheet. The text from the correct sheet does appear. If I go to another sheet and back, the data appears correct.
Is there a way to refresh the sheet so the correct information shows up, or is this a problem to do with the buttons and the macros behind them?

The macro I have used for the go back button:

```
(in workbook):
Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    LastSheet = sh.Name
End Sub

(in module):
Global LastSheet As String

Sub goback()
    Sheets(LastSheet).Visible = True
    Sheets(LastSheet).Activate
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Name <> "BM" Then
                .Range("H9:R31").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    
    Sheets(LastSheet).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Even though there are no calculations, I did try including ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation but that did nothing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am reading this incorrectly but is the issue that the buttons are not dissapearing? if so this may help:

```
    Sub hidebutton()

        Dim sh As Shape

        For Each sh In Sheet1.Shapes

            If sh.Name = "Button 1" Then
        
                sh.Visible = True
    
            End If
        Next
        
      End Sub
```

Comment: ofcourse to hide the buttons you may will need to set visible = false